# Uncaught ReferenceError - Function is not found

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I am developing a website to display data out of a database. There I try to make a url call when I am clicking on a row. To call the url, when the row is clicked I am calling a function, but that function is throwing an error.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: clickableRow is not defined at
>   HTMLTableRowElement.onclick ((index):1)

This is my code in the **editor-view**:

```
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSetMetaData"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Statement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%
    /*
        ...
        Retrieving data of a database
    */
%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="query_result">
            <table id="table" >
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <% 
                            for(int i=1; i<=count; i++){
                                %><th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric"><%
                                    out.print(metaData.getColumnName(i));
                                %></th><%
                            }
                        %>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                    <%
                        while(resultSet.next()){%>
                        <tr onclick="rowClickable(this)" class="n_title"> //<--error is on this line
                               <%for(int i= 1; i<= count; i++){
                                    if(metaData.getColumnName(i).equals("PLANT")){
                                        %><td data-bind="${resultSet.getString(i)}"><%
                                            out.println("<a href='"+resultSet.getString(i)+"'>");
                                                out.println(resultSet.getString(i));
                                            out.println("</a>");
                                        %></td><%
                                    } else {
                                        %><td data-bind="${resultSet.getString(i)}"><%
                                            out.println(resultSet.getString(i));
                                        %></td><%
                                    }
                                }%>
                        </tr>
                        <%}
                    %>                
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function rowClickable(x) {
                alert("Row index is: " + x.rowIndex);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>

<%      connection.close();
    } 
    catch(Exception e){
        out.println("\n<P> SQL error: <PRE> " + e + " </PRE> </P>\n ");
    }
%>
```

This is my code in the **browser-view**:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
        </head>

        <body>
            <div id="query_result">
                <table id="table" >
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">PLANT</th><th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">NAME</th><th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">FILES</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>

                            <tr onclick="rowClickable(this)" class="n_title">//<-- error is on this line
                                   <td data-bind=""><a href='ABI'>ABI</a></td>
                            </tr>

                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function rowClickable(x) {
                alert("Row index is: " + x.rowIndex);
            }
            $("#")
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I hope my code is not too messy :D. Thank you in advance if somebody is able to solve my problem.

Comment: Can you provide the *relevant* html as it is *rendered* (ie browser:view-source).  The relevant part would be the `<tr onclick=` line only.

Comment: As @freedomn-m told you: most likely, the generated page is not as you expect. Please check only the browser side result.

Comment: You Browser view code works correctly (jsbin: http://jsbin.com/wepirivedi/3/edit?html,js,output). maybe your problem is not in HTML code.

Comment: @MahdiAryayi : is it then, that I am using jsp or somewhat?

Comment: Your onClick is event working no issues found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem solves, when the script is imported to the main page, not on the page of ajax call.